# Improve image slider animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i improve image slider transition. It is rather erratic. I want it to be smooth (smooth in and out properly). The problem is image only fadeIn, i cannot figure out how to fadeOut.

```
var nextimage = 0;
var timer = 0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow() {
  if (nextimage >= images.length) {
    nextimage = 0;
  }
  $('.col-md-8')
    .css('background-image', 'url("' + images[nextimage++][0] + '")')
    .fadeIn(3000, function() {
      timer = setTimeout(doSlideshow, 3000);
    });
}

$(".col-md-8").hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});

$(".col-md-8").mouseout(function() {
  setTimeout(doSlideshow, 3000);
});
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/xOPyZR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this for you, you do not need settimeout for this kind of stuff, there are many other ways.

```
function doSlideshow() {
if (nextimage >= images.length) {
nextimage = 0;
}

$('.col-md-8')
.css('background-image', 'url("' + images[nextimage++][0] + '")');
$('.col-md-8').hide().fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
doSlideshow()
});
}
```

Link to codepen, there is bit more to say about this, which I will do later.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PzQwNr

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#top").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cFt5KNrHsHc/TZMH6XUBu-I/AAAAAAAAAR4/R6hOP7lffx0/s1600/apple-logo.png").fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://coreldrawtips.com/images/applebig.jpg').fadeIn().delay(1000);
        });
     }
    );
}, 400
```

[Check this link also.](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/nPh6S/)

Comment: Its my pleasure. @NZMAI